# calculate the integral of $\int_D x\sin(y)$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

> What is $\int_D x\sin(y)\ dA$ where $D$ is the half circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$ above the $x$ axis.

So I got
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^\pi r\cos(\theta)\sin(r \sin(\theta))\ r\ dr\ d \theta.
$$
Then I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Substitute $u = \sin \theta$ then $du = \cos \theta d\theta$ and 
$$
\iint r\cos(\theta)\sin(r \sin(\theta))\ r\ dr\ d \theta
= \int r^2 \left[ \int \sin(ru) du \right] dr
$$

Comment: what about the bounds of integration? as $\sin(0)= \sin(\pi)$ so then u goes from 0 to 0? and so the answer is 0?

Comment: @user42493 didn't think about that. Note that for each point $(x,y)$ in the first quadrant you end up with a point $(-x,y)$ in the second quadrant. $y$ will stay the same, but with $x$ negated, the integral will be zero by symmetry. I.e. integrating over the right quarter-disc and over the left quarter-disc produces opposite values...

Comment: But if it's zero then you don't need any substitution.

Comment: @Aryadeva correct. Leaving the answer as is to benefit people integrating over a different region...

Comment: +1 Yes of course your answer is usefull.